# Value of $\sum^\infty \frac{1}{p_n !}$ =?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The sequence

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{p_i !}$$

with $p_i$ the i-th prime number is apparently convergent, since its strictly increasing and limited by $ e = \sum^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$. What is its value? Can it be expressed in terms of elementary numbers ($e,\pi,...)$?